# How to disallow a user to be logged in from more than one computer?

Tags: php, security, session

I have a website which has a login/logout feature. How can I ensure, 100%, also in a stable technique, that a user won't be a able to login to the same account from two different computers?

Javascript can't be used for this, since it's easy to disable it.

For example, .NET has a Session_End function that executes when a user aborts the connection with the server. How that can be done with PHP?

Thanks, Guy

Comment: I assume you mean that you don't want someome to login to the same account from two different computers at the same time.

Comment: Look at the session id.  It will be unique for each computer.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:** This technique would effectively logout the account on the first computer when logging in on a 2nd.*

When a user logs in, log the session id for the user to the database or equivalent. On each page request, ensure the session id of the user matches the session id stored in the store for their account. Requests from a logged in account with a mismatched session id should be rejected and the user should be logged out.

Comment: This would work, but what if they login via a different browser? Technically the same computer, but will generate a different SESSID.

If you use IP as the identifier, then it's possible that it could be two different computers due to NAT...

I think your answer is the way to go, I'm just playing devil's advocate, as I bet the OP doesn't care about multiple browsers on the same PC.

Comment: Good point; and yeah, IP is no good. I work with schools and they very often have every computer resolve to a single external IP address *(even across dozens of independent school buildings)*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how in depth you want to go.  Most commonly:

- Create a unique session id cookie on login and saved it in the database
- All web pages check the session cookie to make sure it's valid

  - if the session isn't valid, the user is redirected to the login page
- When another user tries to log in, it overwrites the previous session

  - This essentially kicks out the first user

Large companies will also store the IP address in the database as well (so session cookies can't be stolen)

Comment: storing IP in the database will not work, IP can and will change for various valid reason. Think about mobile users or users behind corporate load balancing proxies for example.